# How can I switch the day, week month, and year view in the full calendar using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, view, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I am using latest version of fullcalendar [v6](https://fullcalendar.io/docs).

here my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-example-5xxmkk?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fpolyfills.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) code which was i tried.

I am trying to switch the full calendar view dynamically but am not luck

here is my code.
When I assign all the views here it's working fine with first time.

```
@ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent!: FullCalendarComponent;
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
    initialview: 'dayGridDay'
  };
```

But how can we change the view dynamically like the below code.
I tried multiple ways but did not find any solutions. how can we achieve this?

```
  calendarViewOption(event: any){
    if(event === 1){
      this.calendarComponent.getApi().changeView('dayGridDay');
      this.calendarOptions.plugins = [dayGridPlugin];
    } 
    else if(event === 2) {
      this.calendarComponent.getApi().changeView('timeGridWeek');
      this.calendarOptions.plugins = [timeGridPlugin];
    }
    else if(event === 3) {
        this.calendarComponent.getApi().changeView('dayGridMonth');
        this.calendarOptions.plugins = [dayGridPlugin];
    }
    else if(event === 4) {
      this.calendarComponent.getApi().changeView('multiMonthYear');
      this.calendarOptions.plugins = [multiMonthPlugin,interactionPlugin];
    }

    if (this.calendarComponent) {
      this.calendarComponent.getApi()?.render();
    }
    
  }

<full-calendar #calendar [options]="calendarOptions" id="mxCalendar"></full-calendar>
<button (click)="calendarViewOption(1)">View Day</button>
<button (click)="calendarViewOption(2)">View Week</button>
<button (click)="calendarViewOption(3)">View Month</button>
<button (click)="calendarViewOption(4)">View Multi-Month Year</button>
```

**Edited:**

Using Full Calendar View not changed
The first time it said please make sure you have loaded all necessary plugins I already added all the plugins. I also put the set timeout function.

And the second time it's not giving the error and not updating the view
here is the image

[image]

Comment: Whats the value of `view` property of the calendar component after your changes.
Ref: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view

Comment: Thank you for your reply I edited my question view is not updating while i changing the view.

Comment: Can you add a stackblitz link to reproduce this

Comment: Sure here is the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-example-5xxmkk?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fpolyfills.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Modified to make it work, https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-example-xoyod1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

All you need is to import the plugins and call `changeView`

Comment: Thank you so much it's really appreciated. Can we able to assign new calendar options for particular view? like i want to display 3 month, 6 month or 12 month using multiMonthYear like this => views: {
      multiMonthYear: {
        type: 'multiMonth',
        duration: { months: 3 },
      }

Comment: You can define views with custom settings, yes - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings . You can also add buttons to change to any view (either standard or custom) by putting them in the calendar's header: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/headerToolbar